# Is it possible to run Appcelerator Studio in an EC2 instance and test on device?

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, appcelerator

As my local computer is becoming less powerful I am exploring other options before buying a new one. One of those would be to move my developing environment to an `EC2 instance` and develop from there using a remote connection.

It is my understanding that in theory I would be able to test my apps on the `Android/iOS emulator`, but would I be able to deploy the app to my device if I am running `Appcelerator Studio (eclipse)` on a remote EC2 machine?

If anyone has information of this and can guide me as to what are the possibilities I will appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can rent a [MacInCloud.com](http://www.macincloud.com/features/tools/tools) including Appcelerator Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Mac for iOS development and running a virtualized Mac on EC2 is technically against Apple's licensing and might not be possible (due to virtualization CPU option blocking).

You can check out [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) which does pretty much that for Java. We have a build cloud where we have physical Macs, Windows & Linux machines to build for all targets.